# Physically Based lighting lost after using metal shader on another model?

Tags: scenekit, metal

i got 2 models on my scene (using SceneKit) - ring and diamond. Ring is with gold pbr material (SCNLightingModelPhysicallyBased) - second is diamond with "custom" material using Metal shader (SCNProgram). Right after developing diamond shader my golden ring stopped working and is pure black. Why is that ? When i simply set my ring to yellow and drop pbr lighting model it works, just not pbr - with pbr its solid black. I cant use SCNProgram with PBR ?

[image: metal diamond]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you setting the scene's [`lightingEnvironment`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscene/1639532-lightingenvironment)? You will need a light source in the scene for the object to be lit. You can either use point lights or leverage image-based lighting (IBL) which is what the `lightingEnvironment` is for.

You can also try the [`autoenablesDefaultLighting`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1523812-autoenablesdefaultlighting) property. With it SceneKit will try to adjust and add light sources in the scene depending on its contents, but its behaviour is subject to changes.

Comment: autoenablesDefaultLighting resolved my problem :) dont know how i forgot about it, i thought that setting hdr to lightningEnvironment should be enough.

Comment: Setting `lightningEnvironment` is definitely sufficient to light a PBR material.

Comment: then i dont know why it's not working right with autoenablesDefaultLighting set to false. if i enable it, gold works and i can see my lightningEnvironment reflections also. i'am ok with enabled auto lighting.

Comment: ok i know, no scenekit works like a charm - guys, dont pass your cubemap straight from lightingEnvironment to metal shader unifrom :)